# control inside a repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a repeater control in my aspx page which has a textbox field called "name" and a hidden field called "id" that is the id of the name.

I want to get the value of the id field when the name textbox is in focus and pass it, can you please let me know how i can accomplish that?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td >
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'/>
    </td>

    <td >
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddListNumber" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem Text='First' Value="1" />
          <asp:ListItem Text='Second' Value="0" />
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="txtID" Visible="false" />
  </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"?

Comment: I need  to get the value of the id so I can pass it to some other page

Comment: Ok, just because this seems obvious: Wouldn't the text box lose focus on page navigation? Or is it just supposed to pass the *last* one that was clicked?

Comment: I need to take the id and pass it to the next view (I am using a multiview). I need to take the id with the name in focus and on clicking the next button in that view the values need to be passed on before loading the next view. Not sure if find focus is the best way to explain my problem here but please let me know if you need me to explain further.

Comment: Not sure if I can do this from codebehind directly or need javascript

Comment: I think like you said passing the last one clicked will work also

Comment: @Namekal Sorry. No spoonfeed-helping out here...Not meant of offend you, but we urge that you try implement Bradley's solution by your self? Find your answer. Use Google. And even after that, if you are genuinely stuck with an issue we can help provided you have posted your implementation...

Comment: Thanks deostroll, was not looking for "spoonfeed-helping" was just looking for some guidance being new to it. Took a few days but I figured it out.